# VIN Decoding: Model Year

Tags: decoder, vin

I'm trying to code a simple VIN (ISO 3779) decoder: manufacturer and model year. I'm having some issues w/ decoding the model year, though. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number):

`For passenger cars, and for multipurpose passenger vehicles and trucks with a gross vehicle weight rating of 10,000 lb (4,500 kg) or less, if position 7 is numeric, the model year in position 10 of the VIN refers to a year in the range 1980–2009. If position 7 is alphabetic, the model year in position 10 of VIN refers to a year in the range 2010–2039.`

My car's VIN (Model Year 2012) has the following info:

```
VSS---1--C-------
12345678901234567
```

Manufacturer: SEAT, Model Year: 1982 (Some online VIN decoders give me 1982, some others give me 2012)

How can I modify my decoder so I get this right, other than doing a nasty `if (Manufacturer == "SEAT") Year += 30;`hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having read positions 7 and 10, here's some PHP code:

```
$year = date_1980_2009( $position_10 );  # use your current date function...

if ( preg_match( "/^[A-Z]$/i", $position_7 ) ) $year += 30;  # add 30 years if 7 is alphabetic
```

Having said that, your car doesn't seem to be following the rules.  Exceptional cases require coding exceptions -- which aren't hacks.  Sorry.

Comment: Do you know if there's a table or something of that sort that lists all of these ... exceptions?

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't -- and could not find one.